# how to retrieve data into textfields when i select an option in droplist

Tags: javascript, php

```
<strong>Type Of Party</strong>
<select name="p_name">
    <?php 
        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM party");
        while ($row = $sql->fetch_array()){

            echo '<option value="'.$row['type_party'].'">'.$row['type_party'].'</option>';  
        }
    ?>
    </select>


<p>
    <strong>Max No. Of Children</strong>
    <input type="text" id="txt" name="nocc" placeholder="Type Your children" required="required" />
</p>
```

I want to retrieve data in my textfield with the corresponding data of the option which i select in droplist.
In my table: I have `id`, `Type_party`, `capacity`, and I want to receive `capacity` in textfield when i select type_party in dropdownlist. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Given, you use jQuery, this could easily achieved by storing the capacity in an data attribute.

```
<strong>Type Of Party</strong>
<select name="p_name" >
<?php 
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM party");
while ($row = $sql->fetch_array()){

echo '<option value="'.$row['type_party'].'" data-capacity="' . $row['capacity'] . '">'.$row['type_party'].'</option>';  
}
?>
</select>


<p>
<strong>Max No. Of Children</strong>
<input type="text" id="txt" name="nocc" placeholder="Type Your children" required="required" />
</p>
```

with the following javascript code

```
$('select[name="p_name"]').on('change', function() {
    $('#txt').val($(':selected', this).data('capacity'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple JavaScript

1. you need add the `capacity` attribute of `data-capacity` for the each option
2. Then apply with `onchange` function to select
3. Finally match the [**`selecIndex`**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp) then pass `data-capacity` value to textfield using [**`dataset`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

**JavaScript**

```
 function getvalue(that) {
      documenyt.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = that.options[that.selectedIndex].dataset.capacity
    }
```

**php**

```
    <strong>Type Of Party</strong>
    <select name="p_name" onchange="getvalue(this)">
    <?php 
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM party");
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_array()){

    echo '<option value="'.$row['type_party'].'" data-capacity="'.$row['capacity'].'">'.$row['type_party'].'</option>';  
    }
    ?>
    </select>


    <p>
      <strong>Max No. Of Children</strong>
      <input type="text" id="txt" name="nocc" placeholder="Type Your children" required="required" />
    </p>
```